# How exactly do I create a new, separate page to my website in a Shopify theme?

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I'm working on an e-commerce website that I'm making with Shopify and I've been using the Timber framework and building onto it and modifying it heavily.

Comment: Create it on Shopify in the admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create your page in the Shopify admin.](https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/online-store/pages#add-a-new-webpage-to-your-online-store) The content box can contain HTML or JavaScript; just tap on the `<>` button to see the code.

The page will be rendered with the [page.liquid template](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/templates/page-liquid) of your theme. If you want the FAQ page to have a different look from your other pages you can [create an alternate page template.](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/store/create-alternate-templates)